# Why are BufferViews and Accessors separate in glTF?

Tags: graphics, 3d, gltf

The GLTF format specifies that meshes reference their vertex and index data via accessors, which in turn reference BufferViews. Both of them have an offset and a length.

The main difference seems to be that BufferViews are format-agnostic, they just reference a bunch of bytes, while the accessors are adding type information.

What I do not understand is:

1. Why do both of them need an offset and a length? Which use case is there where the offset in an accessor is not zero and the count of an accessor does not correspond to the length of the view?
2. Why isn't the type data directly contained in the buffer view? In what use case does it make sense to interpret the same data with different formats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format is designed to support interleaved vertex attributes, initially from WebGL (in glTF 1.0) but now more generally across graphics APIs (in glTF 2.0).

For example, `POSITION` data may be a `vec3` of `FLOAT`, but `TEXCOORD_0` data may be a `vec2` of `FLOAT`, and there could even be custom attributes of different types, all interleaved within a single GPU buffer.

So the `BufferView` defines a given byte stride, and the individual accessors into that view may have different types and amounts but will all share the same byte stride.

You're not required to interleave of course, but the format is designed to allow it, and to enforce the byte stride sharing when it happens.

Here's a diagram from the [Data Interleaving section](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_005_BuffersBufferViewsAccessors.md#data-interleaving) of the glTF tutorial.  It's a little small here but you can click for a larger view.  In this example, there are two accessors, one for POSITION and one for NORMAL, sharing a single BufferView.

[image: Data Interleaving]

Comment: When you refer to a GPU buffer, does that correspond to a gltf bufferView, or to a gltf buffer?  (Or is this an implementation decision of the program that reads the gltf file and converts to the graphics API?)

Comment: A GPU buffer corresponds to a specific glTF `bufferView`, not a glTF buffer.  The latter is a bundle of bufferViews, only some of which are intended for the GPU, others may be packed JPG or PNG files, or CPU animation data.  The GLB file format (the packed binary one) is expected to contain only a single buffer, but several bufferViews.